# Migrate multiple Magento 1 instance inside only one multistore Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, database, data-migration, data-migration-tool

I have two Magento 1 I want to migrate to Magento 2 withing the same instance. My goal is to have only one Magento 2 in the end.

- Site A => Magento 1.9.4.0 with 5 website inside
- Site B => Magento 1.9.2.4 with 1 website

I'm looking for the best way to make the migration of the two Magento 1 instance inside the same Magento 2.

What would be the best way ?

1. Merge both Magento 1 inside the same instance the use the data-migration-tool to migrate to magento 2 (not sure how to merge magento 1 instance)
2. Migrate Site A and Site B to their own Magento 2 with the data-migration-tool and then try to merge them (not sure how to merge magento 2 instance)
3. Use the data-migration-tool to migrate site A to Magento 2. Then use the data-migration-tool to migrate site B to the same magento 2 using the delta method (not sure if possible at all)
4. Something else, I'm all ears

Does someone have any idea of the best may ?

Answer (score 1):

I will prefer this way.

1. Merge both Magento 1 inside the same instance the use the data-migration-tool to migrate to magento 2.

So in this one, if any issues comes then it will resolve it self into Magento1 and then perform the Migration.

Comment: Thanks, what method would you suggest to migrate data between magento 1 ? Import/export with the dataflow ?

Comment: Yes, you can use that one.

Comment: If my answer help you, please upvote and accept as solution, so it will help other in community.

Comment: I'll wait until the end of the week to see if I have more answers as I've added a bounty